# String Column Dataframe transformation

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have spark dataframe which has **state** column of **string** datatype

Sample data what it looks like in this column.

```
["Florida"] 
["New jersey", "Colarado", "Texas", "New york"] 
["Florida", "Vermont"]  
["Maine"]   
["Colarado","Texas","New jersey"]
```

I want to transform it so it looks like it within pyspark.

```
Florida
New jersey,Colarado,Texas,New york
Florida,Vermont
Maine
Colarado,Texas,New jersey
```

Can you please help ? Thanks

Comment: Maybe [array_join](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/api/sql/index.html#array_join) is helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Simple regular expression replace can make the result.

```
df.withColumn('value', f.regexp_replace(f.col('value'), '[\[\]"]', '')).show(truncate=False)

+-------------------------------------+
|value                                |
+-------------------------------------+
|New jersey, Colarado, Texas, New york|
+-------------------------------------+
```